# Mysqlierror while insert

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I don’t understand, What am i missing? The $conn is correct and is working with my selects, but the Insert-query refuses to work as i want to...

```
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
$newquestion = $_POST['newquestion']; 
$newanswer = $_POST['newanswer'];

$insertnewquestion = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO      `table` (q_id, question, creator_id) VALUES ('id', '$newquestion', '$userid'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this query, It should must work for your case:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (q_id, question, creator_id) VALUES (NULL, '" . $newquestion . "', '" . $userid . "'")";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

If your q_id is auto increment then you don't need to give its column name and value or you can give its value to NULL so it will auto increment.

Answer (score -2):

INSERT INTO `table` 
(q_id, question, creator_id) 
VALUES ('$id', '$newquestion', '$userid');

Double check your values id => $id

---

Edited:
Or do you mean your q_id is PK and AI?
Just ignore the q_id then.